# Customizing map.resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Suppose I have a Book model, which contains many Page models.

The routing for this would be as so:

```
map.resources :books do |book|
    book.resources :pages
end
```

Following the Rails default on this quickly leads to problems. Suppose Book #1 has 10 pages. The first Page in Book #2 will have this route:

```
/books/2/pages/11
```

This is a pretty bad route, what would make more sense is this:

```
/books/2/pages/1
```

Or even this:

```
/books/2/1
```

Is there a way to still use map.resources, but get a result like this:

```
/books/{book.id}/pages/{page.page_number}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have to use custom routing for that.

Feel free to get inspiration from http://github.com/augustl/kii/blob/master/config/routes.rb

Comment: Wow, that is some crazy routing. Looking at that will definitely help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As August says you need to use custom routing for that.
But for the pages, you don't need the full resources routes. Only show will be necessary.

So something like :

```
map.resources :books do |book|
    book.page ':page_id', :action => 'index'
end
```

Will map the default books url for displaying the index, one book and adding/editing them.
But also a page

> /books/{book.id}/{page_id}

Which maps to the index action with the parameter "page_id". You only have to display the appropriate books page ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the shallow-option for your routing!